# One Page Navigation using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Anybody can help me on how to create a navigation like on this wordpress theme

http://teothemes.com/wp/scrn/

it seems that when you got on top the navigation will just stick below the slider and
when you scroll down the page the navigation will be attached

Comment: Got any code to share?

Comment: Show us [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: none, i just wondering on how it is being created since im used using only one-page nav jquery plugin

Comment: im using scrolldeck.js which is only fixed on top

Comment: Its more than likely this question will be closed because questions should have research done and have some existing code that you are struggling with which we can help you with a specific problem not 'can you give me codes'

Comment: i know how to code, just the part of the nav that is being attached when you scroll down is the prob that im curious on how it is being get done.

Comment: have you tried looking at the src code of the site?

Comment: yes, it seems that it uses a custom javascript function..since i do not know pure javascript..im used only using those ready-made jquery plugins which requires only minor tweaks for customization

Answer (score 1):

Here i show you simple example to make a stiky element:

**HTML snippet codes** :

```
<nav class="sticky">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="#intro">Home</a>
        </li>
        ...        
        <li>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS snippet codes**:

```
nav {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;

nav.fixed{
    position: fixed;  top: 0px;
}
```

Jquery codes:

```
if ($('nav').hasClass('sticky')) {
        var top = $('.sticky').offset().top - parseFloat($('.sticky').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
        $(window).scroll(function (event){
          var y = $(this).scrollTop();
          if (y >= top) {
              $('.sticky').addClass('fixed');
          } else {              
            $('.sticky').removeClass('fixed');
          }
        });
    }
```

here the demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/PBhnE/

but you could also use a plugin like that used on the website http://teothemes.com/wp/scrn/.

http://stickyjs.com/